# Ionic - 4 Image display failed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

The image is not loading in first time compile , but loads perfectly on second compilation
Here is my code

**.html**

```
 <div class="home_main_stack_menu" *ngFor="let service of mainServicesList; let i = index ">
        <ion-row  >
              <ion-col class="textCenter"  >
                <img [src] ="getImage(service.image)">
                <p>{{service.service_name}}</p>
              </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
      </div>
```

**.ts**

```
getImage(imageurl) {
  return 'https://techlabz.in/allorepair' + imageurl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="home_main_stack_menu" *ngFor="let service of mainServicesList; let i =index ">
    <ion-row  >
         <ion-col class="textCenter"  *ngIf="service.image">
           <img [src] ="getImage(service.image)">
           <p>{{service.service_name}}</p>
         </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
 </div>
```

Add just this piece of code  *ngIf="service.image" untill service.image load then show your Pic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="home_main_stack_menu" *ngFor="let service of mainServicesList; let i = index ">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="textCenter">
        <img [src]="’https://techlabz.in/allorepair’+service.image">
        <p>{{service.service_name}}</p>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</div>
```

Try simpler binding for src property? it’s better not to use functions especially for *ngFor replicated templates. Ideally since your images source URL (’https://techlabz.in/allorepair’) is constant - you could run .map method on your mainServicesList array and make sure that each item (service)'s image property (service.image) already has full URL for template to use.

Also see if you need to sanitize image URLs using [Angular’s sanitizer.](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusturl)